# Jupyter Notebook won't display graphs on Gitlab

Tags: python, gitlab, jupyter

Although I use `"%matplotlib inline"`, I cannot get my publically shared notebook to display graphs (but it does display dataFrames...?):

https://gitlab.com/kim.rants/jupyter_notebooks_thesis/blob/master/feature_extraction.ipynb

See output 10 and 11.

Any advice?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I get `"feature_extraction.ipynb" did not exist on "master"`. In the folder 'feature_extraction' there are two notebooks.